# Firefox NoScript and Hola Unblocker not working together

Tags: firefox, noscript

I'm having issues with some Firefox extensions. I'd like to use the NoScript extension but it mess around with Hola unblocker (which I mainly use for Pandora because I'm from Europe).
When NoScript is installed it crashes Hola. I tried to unblock Pandora in NoScript, no success, I have to uninstall it in order to make it work.

Does anyone have a fix/tweak/hack for this? Even if it doesn't really fix the issue, I just would like to browse Pandora with NoScript.

Comment: Try contacting the author of Hola about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://hola.org, and allow hola.org, cloudflare.com and cloudfront.net
This will allow the extension to connect to the hola website (where it gets the list of 'proxies' from that you can use).
If this doesn't work, you can try:

- to reinstall Hola Unblocker
- to reinstall NoScript
- to reinstall both
- to [reset Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems), install both extensions again and allow aforementioned websites with NoScript.

It could also be that you just have to wait some time. I just had the same problem: for a long time it couldn't connect, and suddenly it worked again!

Answer (score 0):

Just add following addresses to NoScript Whitelist:

1. 127.0.0.1
2. hola.org
3. cloudflare.com
4. cloudfront.net

Comment: As of late 2015, you need to whitelist the following site: - hola.org - cloudflare.com - netdna-cdn.com